# Tratamento específico para Grupos de Objetos inseridos na Caixa de Ferramentas do VBA (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, objetos

Devido a ações repetitivas com grupos de objetos que crio para funcionarem como se fossem um único objeto, agrupei alguns destes objetos (com o botão direito do mouse e selecionando agrupar...), e **arrastei** para dentro da **caixa de ferramentas** do **VBA**.

Para minha surpresa deu certo, surgiu um ícone editável e que permite que eu recrie de uma única vez cada grupo de objetos que preciso usar repetidamente em partes diferentes do projeto ou mesmo em outros projetos.

Porém, há alguns inconvenientes em se trabalhar desta forma, listo alguns deles que são importantes para mim:

1. O "grupo" criado não é identificado como um novo objeto (evidentemente), então deve-se trabalhar com cada objeto de um grupo como se ele fosse um objeto colocado individualmente. continuando esses objetos agrupados ou não (de fato são simplesmente novos objetos colocados individualmente no formulário).
2. Pelo fato de serem objetos distintos, a mesma lógica de nomeação sequencial de cada objeto é seguida, por exemplo, cada grupo que tenha um único **Label** inserido no formulário gera o **Label1**, **Label2**, **Label3**, etc. Então se entre um grupo e outro for colocado no formulário alguns objetos do mesmo tipo de alguns que existam nestes grupos, um **Label** que seria o **Label7** na inclusão do grupo, passa a ser **Label9**, pois dois **Labels** foram colocados antes deste grupo. Portanto, é preciso verificar "**objeto a objeto**" do grupo, que nome ele recebeu para tratar no código.

**Mostro a seguir um exemplo meramente didático.**

1. Neste formulário estão presentes os objetos: **Frame1, Image1, Label1, commandButton1 e commandButton2**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Estes objetos foram **agrupados** (botão direito do mouse):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. O grupo resultante foi **arrastado para a caixa de ferramentas** (vide o ícone do planeta terra, modifiquei para ficar claro a adição do grupo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Na sequência **foram criados** um grupo (à direita do primeiro), um Label normal (abaixo deles) e mais um grupo (abaixo do Label):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O nome dos novos objetos ficaram assim:

- **Frame2, Image2, Label2, commandButton3 e commandButton4** para o segundo grupo
- **Label3** para o Label inserido no formulário
- **Frame3, Image3, Label4, commandButton5 e commandButton6** para o terceiro  grupo

Repare que o **Label** do terceiro grupo fica com o valor **4** e não acompanha os demais do grupo, o que impede um tratamento rígido no código.

**PERGUNTA:**

**Há uma forma de se fazer isso obtendo nomes diferentes para os objetos ou gerar propriedades para esse grupo da caixa de ferramentas?**

Por exemplo, se o nome de cada objeto do grupo da **caixa de ferramentas** (por absurdo) pudesse receber um nome qualquer, cada novo objeto criaria estes objetos com a numeração esperada (o **Label** do grupo poderia chamar **Legenda**, gerando **Legenda1**, **Legenda2**, **Legenda3**, etc. não interferindo com a nomeação dos **Labels** que não sejam de um desses grupos).

Uma forma que também resolveria é se para esse grupo fossem associadas **propriedades**, o que permitiria, por exemplo, registrar uma "**id**" para cada grupo criado, ou mesmo algum texto de referência.

**Tem como fazer?**

Tenho certo conhecimento e pouca experiência em linguagens voltadas a eventos ou objetos, portanto, acredito que tenha uma forma mais adequada de se tratar este caso.

Comment: Tá, eu entendi o "problema". Mas a pergunta é? E dai? O que essa "má-formação" de nomes te impede ou prejudica? O fato de você ter Frame3, Image3, ..., Label4, ... é realmente um problema? Se por acaso você tem código que manipula esses elementos assumindo que os nomes deles terão sempre o mesmo número de terminação, talvez essa tenha sido uma péssima escolha. Pra ter um código genérico, não seria mais fácil (e correto) acessar os objetos dentro do frame (o objeto container principal) através da propriedade `Controls` do frame?

Comment: Por exemplo, assim: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d411f921-998c-4d8f-a4be-fcb5034642c9/excel-vba-iterate-controls-inside-frame?forum=exceldev

Comment: Luiz, já estou preparando com os controls que no meu caso é trabalhoso (envolve várias labels e imagens para recursos gráficos que tenho como padrão), vou fazer para este exemplo e colocar aqui, mas gostaria de saber se não era o caso de criar uma Classe. Não sei trabalhar com classes e me parece que por meio delas eu posso também criar propriedades.

Comment: Uma pergunta que ajudará muito, tem como eu saber a id ou o índice de um objeto específico, sem ter de "varrer" todos os objetos do formulário para encontrá-lo? Com isso eu resolvo facilmente o problema e de forma direta.

Comment: Sim, tem como saber o índice específico. É na ordem de criação. Assim, como você gerou um "template" na toolbar, os elementos vão ser criados na mesma ordem. Então pegar pelo índice também é uma boa ideia. :) Sobre classes, vc tem razão. Talvez seja mesmo o melhor caminho. Tenho pouquíssima experiência com OO em VBA, mas certamente tem muito material na Internet que pode te ajudar.

Comment: Ok, o que queria saber de fato é se tem uma função que retorna o índice do objeto, por exemplo:  id = IndiceDoObjeto(Label5), claro que posso criar esta função, mas teria algo do tipo no VBA? Não localizei.

Comment: Mas se vc vai pegar o índice do objeto pelo nome, não adianta nada. É mais fácil pegar o nome. Eu imaginei que vc armazenaria os índices fixos, e ai pegaria via `Controls(indice)`.

Comment: Oi Luiz, não entendi seu comentário, você pensou em algo diferente do que apresentei na resposta? Eu usei índices fixos tanto para identificar cada grupo de objetos, como para identificar cada objeto dentro de seu grupo, os Controls(índice). Qual seria a outra opção?

Comment: Então, na verdade eu tinha imaginado que os índices funcionariam de forma diferente no VBA: com hierarquia de filhos quando se adiciona um controle dentro de um frame, assim os índices seriam por controle "pai". Porque se for pra fazer assim, do jeito da sua resposta, vai ficar inviável, não? (se o Label3 não existir, seu código não funciona mais).

Comment: Tem razão, na versão profissional eu fiz uma rotina para quando o formulário inicializar seja procurada a id do objeto pelo nome dele (a id seria o índice conforme o respectivo Control no formulário, procurado dentro de um For Next), por exemplo: id = IndiceDoObjeto(Userform1, "Frame3"). Caso o objeto não seja encontrado, informo e finalizo o programa para acertar o erro. Deste modo, fica indiferente a inserção ou deleção de objetos, desde que não sejam deletados objetos pertencentes a um grupo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução apresentada abaixo (**código e formulário com o resultado dos testes**) foi feita usando "**Controls**" para tratar os objetos de cada grupo.

```
Private Sub CommandButtonTeste_Click()

    Dim Bandeira As Variant

    'Pega o ícone da bandeira desejada
    Set Bandeira = LoadPicture("F:\Teste\Japao.ico")

    'Teste #1: Altera todos os dados do primeiro grupo
    GrupoDeObjetos 1, True, True, _
                   "Japão", _
                   Bandeira, _
                   "Arroz", _
                   "Perda", _

                   "Troca"

    'Teste #2: Torna os objetos do Segundo grupo invisíveis
    GrupoDeObjetos 2, False, True

    'Teste #3: Desabilita os objetos do terceiro grupo
    GrupoDeObjetos 3, True, False

    'Teste #4: Força um erro, pois o grupo 4 não existe
    GrupoDeObjetos 4, True, True

End Sub


Public Sub GrupoDeObjetos( _
           ByVal IndiceDoGrupo As Integer, _
           ByVal GrupoVisivel As Boolean, _
           ByVal GrupoHabilitado As Boolean, _
  Optional ByVal LegendaDoFrame As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal Imagem As Variant = "", _
  Optional ByVal LegendaDaImagem As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal LegendaDoBotao1 As String = "", _
  Optional ByVal LegendaDoBotao2 As String = "")

    Dim i As Integer

    'Verifica o índice
    If IndiceDoGrupo < 1 Or IndiceDoGrupo > 3 Then

        Beep

        MsgBox "Índice do Grupo de Objetos inválido!" & _
                Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
               "Índice: " & IndiceDoGrupo

        Exit Sub

    End If

    'Tratamento dos objetos do grupo
    ' Atualiza o índice do grupo com o valor
    ' do índice dos controles no formulário
    Select Case IndiceDoGrupo

        Case 1

            'Índice do Frame1 no formulário
            IndiceDoGrupo = 0

        Case 2

            'Índice do Frame2 no formulário
            IndiceDoGrupo = 5

        Case 3

            'Índice do Frame3 no formulário
            IndiceDoGrupo = 11

    End Select

    'Atualiza dados do objeto se os dados foram passados
    If LegendaDoFrame <> "" Then Me.Controls(IndiceDoGrupo).Caption = LegendaDoFrame
    If Imagem <> "" Then Me.Controls(IndiceDoGrupo + 1).Picture = Imagem
    If LegendaDaImagem <> "" Then Me.Controls(IndiceDoGrupo + 2).Caption = LegendaDaImagem
    If LegendaDoBotao1 <> "" Then Me.Controls(IndiceDoGrupo + 3).Caption = LegendaDoBotao1
    If LegendaDoBotao2 <> "" Then Me.Controls(IndiceDoGrupo + 4).Caption = LegendaDoBotao2

    'Trata os objeto do grupo (Visible/Enabled)
    For i = 0 To 4

        'Grupo visível ou não
        Me.Controls(IndiceDoGrupo + i).Visible = GrupoVisivel

        'Grupo habilitado ou não
        Me.Controls(IndiceDoGrupo + i).Enabled = GrupoHabilitado

    Next i

End Sub
```

Observe no **código** que o **IndiceDoGrupo** é uma única variável tratada de dois modos diferentes:

**1.** Ao se chamar a rotina este índice aponta para o grupo desejado, neste caso os grupos de valores **1**, **2** e **3**.

**2.** No código, conforme o grupo escolhido para tratar, esta variável recebe o valor do índice do **Frame** do grupo, neste caso **0**, **5** e **11** respectivamente para os grupos **1**, **2** e **3**.

Repare que cada grupo tem **5** objetos, como o **grupo 2** foi criado imediatamente após o **grupo 1**, o índice de seu **Frame** é o **5**. (os objetos do grupo 1 tem os índices: 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4)

A diferença do índice do **grupo 3** ser **11** e não **10**, é que o **Label3** foi inserido no formulário antes desse grupo, portanto, o **Label3** obteve o índice **10**.

**IMPORTANTE!**

Para que este código funcione adequadamente, ao criar seu grupo de objetos **insira cada objeto do grupo na sequência que pretende trabalhar**, e não insira nenhum outro objeto que não seja deste grupo até terminá-lo.

**Agrupe-o**, coloque na **caixa de ferramentas** e pronto, basta tratar o índice de cada novo objeto que colocar no formulário (neste caso, iniciando de 1).

**Este é o resultado dos testes:**

[image: Resultado dos testes]

Observe que são quatro testes, mas não apresentei a caixa de diálogo gerada pelo erro proposital do **teste #4** (ela foi fechada antes do **PrintScreen**), para ficar fácil identificar na imagem acima o ocorrido:

**1.** Todos os dados do **grupo 1** foram alterados, incluindo a imagem da bandeira

**2.** O **grupo 2** ficou invisível

**3.** O **grupo 3** ficou desabilitado, porém, apesar da imagem também estar desabilitada, ela não fica "esmaecida" (não fiz este efeito no exemplo)

**4.** A mensagem de erro causada por se chamar um quarto grupo que não existe no formulário gerou a mensagem de erro apropriada (não apresentei)

**COMPLEMENTO**

Caso o **Label3** seja deletado do formulário, o índice do terceiro objeto mudará, para resolver isso pode-se criar uma rotina para buscar o índice do primeiro objeto do grupo ao se inicializar o formulário, por exemplo.

Sugestão simples de chamada da rotina:

```
    Dim Indice1, Indice2, Indice3 as Integer

    Indice1 = IndiceDoObjeto(UserForm1, "Frame1")
    Indice2 = IndiceDoObjeto(UserForm1, "Frame2")
    Indice3 = IndiceDoObjeto(UserForm1, "Frame3")
```

Caso o objeto não seja localizado no formulário eu indicaria informar por meio de uma mensagem e sair do programa imediatamente após a mensagem, pois não faz sentido prosseguir havendo este tipo de erro.

Desta forma não ocorrerá erros ao manipular objetos entre os grupos.

**ORGANIZAÇÃO NA ORDEM DOS ÍNDICES DOS OBJETOS NO GRUPO**

Ao trabalhar com grupos deste tipo (bem mais extensos), me deparei com um problema que pode ocorrer de duas formas:

1. Se os objetos de um grupo não foram criados na ordem desejada ou intuitiva (a partir do primeiro de cima à esquerda até o último de baixo à direita), o índice de cada objeto no grupo evidentemente não acompanhará esta ordem, o que dificulta - pelo menos - o tratamento inicial dos mesmos no código.
2. Se for alterada a posição ou ordem de exposição do objeto no formulário, com o "Trazer para frente" ou "Enviar para trás", por exemplo, os índices dos objetos no formulário são alterados, então pode ocorrer de um objeto do grupo ser "substituído" por outro no tratamento aos objetos do grupo ou mesmo todos os objetos terem seus índices alterados (caso de trazer para frente um objeto que foi criado antes do grupo).

Como solução, fiz um teste, passei a ordenar os objetos conforme o desejado, de forma que seus índices ficassem na ordem "intuitiva". Para tanto, fiz isso em um novo formulário, para não haver problema com outros objetos que poderiam interferir neste processo.

Então, sem precisar "reagrupar", pois permaneceram "agrupados" mesmo com os recursos do tipo "Avançar" e "Recuar", por exemplo, ao final o coloquei na caixa de ferramentas.

Neste momento, este novo grupo ficou ordenado como desejado, ou seja, ao inseri-lo em qualquer formulário, a ordem dos índices de seus objetos mantêm a ordem em que alterei no grupo.

**SOLICITAÇÃO**

Caso existam outras formas de se fazer isso, inclusive por meio de **Classes de objetos** com propriedades para passar estes dados, se puderem postar aqui um exemplo eu ficaria muito grato!

Comment: Pessoal, caso alguém possa fazer algo similar ou um exemplo com Classes de objetos, eu poderia criar outra pergunta se for o melhor a fazer, pois preciso aprender trabalhar com Classes, sei que vai ser muito útil para .mim e acredito que para outros também.